# Find a set of parametric equations for the tangent line to the curve of intersection of the surface at the given point

Tags: vector-spaces, partial-derivative, tangent-line

The given is
$$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$3x-5y+7z=24$$
$$(3,4,5)$$
First we find the gradient of first equation which we'll call $F_{(x,y,z)}$
$$F_{(x,y,z)}= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-z$$
$$F_{(x,y,z)}= \left<\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},-1 \right>$$
Now. for the second which we'll call $G_{x,y,z}$
$$G_{x,y,z}=\left<3,-5,7 \right>$$
Now we take the cross product of the two vectors which is:
$$\left<\frac{3}{5}, \frac{-36}{5}, \frac{-27}{5} \right>$$
Now if we multiply the cross product by $\frac{5}{3}$ we get
$$\left<1,-12,-9\right>$$
So our parametric equations are:
$$\frac{x-3}{1} ,\frac{y-4}{-12}, \frac{z-5}{-9}$$
I have checked all my work and I'm 99.9% sure I have it all right but the website we are using for turning in our homework says it is wrong.

Comment: You are right, just set your ratios equal and equal to $t$.

Comment: Another way: $(z-5)^2+10(z-5)-(y-4)^2-8(y-4)-(x-3)^2-6(x-3)=0$ and $7(z-5)-5(y-4)+3(x-3)=0,$ i.e. tangent plane $10(z-5)-8(y-4)-6(x-3)=0$ and $7(z-5)-5(y-4)+3(x-3)=0,$ or $x-3 = -\frac{t}{9}, y-4 = \frac43 t, z-5 = t.$